# Transpile with babel after npm install

Tags: npm, babeljs

I installed this package: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-authentication-local (question not related specifically to this package). This package's source code is in `./src`, and `npm run compile` puts the babel-transpiled code into `./lib`, which is the main entry point.

My question is, after I do `npm install feathers-authentication-local`, how does npm know that it needs to run `npm run compile`? I thought of putting a `postinstall` script in `package.json`, this package doesn't have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding what is uploaded to npm when publishing, there are two fields in package.json, files and directories, which are used to specify what should be uploaded.

Take a look as well to "main" property, it points to the files that will be used when importing a module in your aplication so:

```
import foo from 'foo'
```

Will look into node_modules/foo/$(main) which in this case points to lib/

Answer (score 0):

The package actually doesn't compile after install on client's machines, but it's probably compiled on the mantainer's machine and then published on NPM.

Compiling process is fired by the `prepublish` script in `package.json`.

Comment: The `lib/` folder is in .gitignore. So when you `npm publish`, it publishes everything in that folder, not only what is tracked by git? In this case is `node_modules/` published too?

Comment: `node_modules` is not published by default. [Read here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) for more info about excluded files defaults. `lib/` folder is actually explicitly included (or not ignored) by `.npmignore`: notice the `!` at the beginning of `!lib/`.

Comment: How about what's written in the accepted answer? "two fields in package.json, files and directories, which are used to specify what should be uploaded". What if I put `directories: ["lib/"]` in package.json, and ignore `lib/` in .npmignore?

Comment: I'd suggest you to check NPM docs to have a better understanding of how NPM publishing works: [NPM developers guide](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers) and [NPM package.json handling](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) with both **files** and **directories** definitions.